# How to Pass an Array to and from a Function?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, subroutine

(Fair Warning, I am self taught on VBA so I apologize in advance for any cringe-worthy coding or notations.)
I have an estimating worksheet in excel. The worksheet will have a section for the user to input variables (which will be an array). The first input variable will "reset" the remaining input variables to a standard value when the first variable is changed. The standard values for the input variables are stored in a function in a module. I am attempting to fill the input variable array with the standard values from the function and then display those values on the sheet. I was easily able to do this without arrays but have had no luck in moving everything into arrays.

This is for excel 2010. I previously did not use arrays and created a new variable when needed, however the estimating sheet has grown much larger and it would be better to use arrays at this point. I have googled this question quite a bit, played around with removing and adding parenthesis, changing the type to Variant, trying to set the input variable array to be a variable that is an array (if that makes sense?), and briefly looked into ParamArray but that does not seem applicable here.

```
Dim BearingDim(1 To 9, 1 To 4, 1 To 8) As Range
Dim arrBearingGeneral(1 To 5, 1 To 8) As Range
Dim Test As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Set General Variable array to cells on the worksheet
For i = 1 To 5
 For j = 1 To 8
  Set arrBearingGeneral(i, j) = Cells(9 + i, 3 + j)
 Next j
Next i
'Set Bearing Input Variables to Cells on the Worksheet
For p = 1 To 4
 For i = 1 To 9
  Select Case p
   Case Is = 1
    Set BearingDim(i, p, 1) = Cells(16 + i, 4)
   Case Is = 2
    Set BearingDim(i, p, 1) = Cells(27 + i, 4)
   Case Is = 3
    Set BearingDim(i, p, 1) = Cells(37 + i, 4)
   Case Is = 4
    Set BearingDim(i, p, 1) = Cells(49 + i, 4)
   End Select
 Next i
Next p
'Autopopulate standard input variables based on Bearing Type
inputMD_StdRocker BearingType:=arrBearingGeneral(1, 1), _         
arrBearingDim:=BearingDim
End Sub

Sub inputMD_StdRocker(ByVal BearingType As String, ByRef _
arrBearingDim() As Variant)
Dim arrBearingDim(1 To 9, 1 To 4)
    Select Case BearingType
        Case Is = "MF50-I"
            For j = 1 To 2
                arrBearingDim(2, j) = 20
                arrBearingDim(3, j) = 9
                arrBearingDim(4, j) = 1.75
            Next j
                arrBearingDim(5, 1) = 15
'There are numerous more select case, but those were removed to keep it 
'short
    End Select
End Sub
```

The expected output is my "BearingDim" Array will have certain array index values set to a standard value from the "inputMD_StdRocker" function. Then those values will be displayed in the cell that corresponds to the array index. 
Currently, I get a compile error "Type Mismatch, Array or User-Defined Type Expected". I have been able to get around the type mismatch by removing the () from "arrBearingDim()" in the function title for "inputMD_StdRocker" however, it will not pass the values back to my "BearingDim" array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's your `Function`?

Comment: `BearingDim` is `As Range()`. So the `ByRef arrBearingDim() As Variant` must be `ByRef arrBearingDim() As Range`, and you cannot `Dim` it again inside the sub. You can `redim` it though if that is what you want to achieve, but then what's the point of filling it up before calling the sub only to erase it in the sub?

Comment: In your `inputMD_StdRocker` sub, you're re-defining `arrBearingDim` to a different size. What's your intention here?

Comment: `ByRef arrBearingDim() As Variant` You're passing in a `Range()`, so declare it as a `Range`: `ByRef arrBearingDim() As Range`. No need to make it jump through all the implicit conversions from `Variant` to `Range`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I have changed the "ByRef arrBearingDim() as Variant" to "ByRef arrBearingDim() As Range". This actually allows the code to progress into the "inputMD_StdRocker" sub but now I get an "Run Time Error 9: Subscript out of Range" when it tries to read the code line "arrBearingDim(2, j) = 20

Comment: i also removed the Dim arrBearingDim(1 to 9, 1 to 4)  entirely from the inputMD sub

Comment: Well, `BearingDim` has three dimensions, you are trying to access it as if it had two.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to what (I think) is a misunderstanding you have of how to use arrays. There are a few problems in your code.

First, you're defining a two-dimensional and a three-dimensional array of `Ranges` when I believe you really only want to store the **values** captured from the worksheet. (*If I'm wrong, then you are never initializing the array of `Ranges`, so none of the ranges in the array actually point to anything.*)

Secondly, it looks as if your initial array `arrBearingGeneral` is always filled from the same (static) area of the worksheet. If this is so (and you really do want the values from the cells, not an array of Range objects), then you can create a memory-based array (read this [website, especially section 19](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)). So the first part of your code can be reduced to

```
'--- create and populate a memory-based array
Dim bearingDataArea As Range
Dim arrBearingGeneral(1 To 5, 1 To 8) As Variant
Set bearingDataArea = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10:K14")
arrBearingGeneral = bearingDataArea.Value
```

Optionally of course you can calculate the range of your data instead of hard-coding it ("D10:K14"), but this example follows your own example.

While this isn't a complete answer, hopefully it clears up an issue to get you farther down the road.

Comment: Ok, I am / have read the website you mention, it is very useful. So as far as the 2 arrays in question (BearingDim & arrBearingDim): BearingDim is a 3-D (i, j, k) array with the i representing rows on the sheet, j represents essentially a continuation of the rows on the sheet but in terms of calculating, will need to be separate, & k is for essentially a second (i, k) setup. Meanwhile, arrBearingDim is intended to be the values to fill in the (i, j) on the BearingDim array while k is which column is currently changing.

Comment: So the idea is in the Input Variable section of the worksheet, every column (k) is considered a new separate bearing. The rows in the Input Variable section are Dimensions of components of the bearings (i.e. Plate length or Plate Width, etc..). The third part of the array (or in this case, the middle number (j)) is the Component Number for the bearing. So BearingDim(2,1,3) would represent something like "Bearing 3, Component Part 1, Plate Length", where (2,1,3) 2 = Plate length, 1 = Component Number, 3 = Bearing Number. Hopefully this clarifies things a little bit.

Comment: My reasoning behind leaving arrBearingDim as a 2-D array is that it wont matter which bearing number is currently being reset. Just that the values for i and j get carried over to the BearingDim array. But I may be thinking about this incorrectly.

Comment: So in your data there are: 9 different plate lengths, 4 different component numbers, and 8 different bearing numbers. You're trying to build a set of data that collects data on all the various combinations of these parts? (288 values total)

Comment: @GSerg, Thank you for all the help. I changed to arrBearingDim array to be 3-D and it works! (for 1 bearing at least). Now I just need to figure out how to make sure it assigns the values to the right bearing. Thanks again for all the quick responses, I am sure I will have plenty more questions in the future.

Comment: That's correct Peter. Well there are 9 different Plate Dimensions (i.e. Length, width, radius, thickness, etc...) Eventually all of this data will be used in calculations later in the spreadsheet.

Comment: The idea is that for each bearing, there's a possibility of 4 different components (some bearings will only have 2 or 3 or all 4). Each of these components has 9 different dimensions possible to them (some of these dimensions may end up being 0 for some of the components). For ALL components (even the bearings the don't have all 4 components) calculations will be run to estimate costs and machining times.

Comment: The calculations will be the same regardless of the number of components the arbitrary bearing has. To save on input time and error, i want to have the spreadsheet auto-fill the component dimensions for the bearings based on the bearing type selected as the first input variable. (the bearing type will determine the number of components the bearing will actually have and enter 0 for all dimensions on a component that is not used.)

Comment: So hence, an array of all bearing data (BearingDim(i, j, k)) where "i" is the component dimensions (length, width, thickness, etc...), "j" is the component number (component 1, 2, 3, or 4), and "k" is the bearing number. And then the "inputMD_StdRocker" sub will input the correct "i" value for the "j" component for the bearing number that is affected.

Comment: To clarify, the spreadsheet will have a up to 8 different bearings shown. The different bearings are isolated to one column (i.e. everything in column "D" pertains to bearing number 1, everything in column "E" pertains to bearing number 2, etc..). The first input variable for each column is to select the "BearingType"

Comment: Sounds like you have a good idea of your data and what you have in mind to implement your solution. Continue to work it through and we look forward to helping you to answer other questions as they arise.

Comment: Thanks again @PeterT. Your help has been much appreciated. I know there is some kind of feedback for those who answer questions on here but I am also new to Stack Overflow so I don't know how to properly give credit yet.

Comment: If you wish, it's just a click on the checkmark and/or the up arrow on the left, next to the top of the answer. Good luck!